# How to tail -f the latest log file with a given pattern

Tags: linux, logging, zsh, tail

I work with some log system which creates a log file every hour, like follows:

```
SoftwareLog.2010-08-01-08
SoftwareLog.2010-08-01-09
SoftwareLog.2010-08-01-10
```

I'm trying to tail to follow the latest log file giving a pattern (e.g. SoftwareLog*) and I realize there's:

```
tail -F (tail --follow=name --retry)
```

but that only follow one specific name - and these have different names by date and hour.  I tried something like:

```
tail --follow=name --retry SoftwareLog*(.om[1])
```

but the wildcard statement is resoved before it gets passed to tail and doesn't re-execute everytime tail retries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Edit: after a quick googling for a tool]

You might want to try out multitail - http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

If you want to stick with Dennis Williamson's answer (and I've +1'ed him accordingly) here are the blanks filled in for you.

In your shell, run the following script (or it's zsh equivalent, I whipped this up in bash before I saw the zsh tag):

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_DIR="some/logfiles/"
SYMLINK_FILE="SoftwareLog.latest"
SYMLINK_PATH="$TARGET_DIR/$SYMLINK_FILE"

function getLastModifiedFile {
    echo $(ls -t "$TARGET_DIR" | grep -v "$SYMLINK_FILE" | head -1)
}

function getCurrentlySymlinkedFile {
    if [[ -h $SYMLINK_PATH ]]
    then
        echo $(ls -l $SYMLINK_PATH | awk '{print $NF}')
    else
        echo ""
    fi
}

symlinkedFile=$(getCurrentlySymlinkedFile)
while true
do
    sleep 10
    lastModified=$(getLastModifiedFile)
    if [[ $symlinkedFile != $lastModified ]]
    then
        ln -nsf $lastModified $SYMLINK_PATH
        symlinkedFile=$lastModified
    fi
done
```

Background that process using the normal method (again, I don't know zsh, so it might be different)...

`./updateSymlink.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Then `tail -F $SYMLINK_PATH` so that the tail hands the changing of the symbolic link or a rotation of the file.

This is slightly convoluted, but I don't know of another way to do this with tail.  If anyone else knows of a utility that handles this, then let them step forward because I'd love to see it myself too - applications like Jetty by default do logs this way and I always script up a symlinking script run on a cron to compensate for it.

[Edit: Removed an erroneous 'j' from the end of one of the lines. You also had a bad variable name "lastModifiedFile" didn't exist, the proper name that you set is "lastModified"]

Comment: thanks, I might have to do that.  I looked into multitail, but unfortunately it's interactive only which means I can't pipe it's output elsewhere.  I'll try it and see where I get.  The thing is I would like this to only run when the tail is running and exit when that exits, and i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically the only solution I liked (and I searched a lot for this).

Comment: Neato. Edited to fix a bug where it wouldn't work the first time for me. (Because getCurrentlySymlinkedFile was returning an empty string, and the typo'd nonexistent lastModifiedDate also evaluated to an empty string.)

Answer (score 13):

I believe the simplest solution is as follows:

```
tail -f `ls -tr | tail -n 1`
```

Now, if your directory contains other log files like "SystemLog" and you only want the latest "SoftwareLog" file, then you would simply include a grep as follows:

```
tail -f `ls -tr | grep SoftwareLog | tail -n 1`
```

Comment: or use head instead of tail, to make things simpler =) 
ls -t | head -1 | xargs tail -F

Comment: Or may be use : ```tail -f SoftwareLog.`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H'` ```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this, but an approach that may work would be to run a background process that creates and updates a symlink to the latest log file and then you would `tail -f` (or `tail -F`) the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN="$1"

# Try to make sure sub-shells exit when we do.
trap "kill -9 -- -$BASHPID" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

PID=0
OLD_FILES=""
while true; do
  FILES="$(echo $PATTERN)"
  if test "$FILES" != "$OLD_FILES"; then
    if test "$PID" != "0"; then
      kill $PID
      PID=0
    fi
    if test "$FILES" != "$PATTERN" || test -f "$PATTERN"; then
      tail --pid=$$ -n 0 -F $PATTERN &
      PID=$!
    fi
  fi
  OLD_FILES="$FILES"
  sleep 1
done
```

Then run it as: `tail.sh 'SoftwareLog*'`

The script will lose some log lines if the logs are written to between checks. But at least it's a single script, with no symlinks required.

Answer (score 0):

We have daily rotating log files as: `/var/log/grails/customer-2020-01-03.log`. To `tail` the latest one, the following command worked fine for me:

```
tail -f /var/log/grails/customer-`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`.log
```

(**NOTE:** no space after the `+` sign in the expression)

So, for you, the following should work (if you are in the same directory of the logs):

```
tail -f SoftwareLog.`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is to use **tail** with **ls** and **head**, try something like this

```
tail -f `ls -t SoftwareLog* | head -1`
```